# Question about the non-renormalization of conserved currents

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

It is asserted in many places, e.g, sec. 12.4 in Peskin&Schroeder, that the current
$J^\mu=\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$ needs no renormalization.

The following diagram

[image]

contributes a divergence of $Z_1$-like, which is equal to a $Z_2$-like divergence by Ward identity. Then this divengence can be removed by the renormalization factor $\sqrt{Z_2}$ of $\psi$ in $J^\mu$. So there's no need for a further renormalization of $J^\mu$ as asserted.

However, the following diagram

[image]

seems to contribute a $Z_3$-like divergence. $J^\mu$ has to mix with $A^\mu$ to remove this divergence, contradicting that $J^\mu$ needs no renormalization. Is there any problems?

On the other hand, the equation of motion reads
$$ Z_3[\partial^2 A^\mu - \partial^\mu(\partial\cdot A)] = - Z_1 e J^\mu \,.$$
While $A^\mu$ is already renormalized, $J^\mu$ also needs no renormalization as asserted. So we should have $Z_3=Z_1$ up to finite terms, which is not correct?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137688/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/612620/2451

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the current does mix with $A^\mu$, or $\partial_\nu F^{\nu\mu}$ more precisely, as discussed in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512187) written by J. C. Collins et al. (I fount it from [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224511/why-conserved-current-should-not-need-renormalization/435880#435880) in PSE). I quote from the abstract:

> It is commonly asserted that the electromagnetic current is conserved and therefore is not renormalized. Within QED we show (a) that this statement is false

and

> The current mixes with the four-divergence of the electromagnetic field-strength tensor.

Comment: Just piggy backing off of this nice answer to point out that the diagram in Fig 3 of the paper by Collins et al (showing an example of an operator requiring renormalization of the current) is exactly the same diagram as the one in the question.